# Asyncio process blocking

Tags: python, asynchronous

So i have a basic discord bot which accepts input

```
import discord
import asyncio
import threading

loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
bot  = discord.Client()

def run_asyncio_loop(loop):
    asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
    loop.run_forever()

Hangman.set_bot(bot)

@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    bot.loop.create_task(Hangman.main(message))


asyncioLoop = threading.Thread(target = run_asyncio_loop, args = (loop,))
asyncioLoop.start()

bot.run(BotConstants.TOKEN)
```

In this example it calls the hangman game which does not block anything as i have tested this using `asyncio.sleep(n)` but when i go to do a something in hangman it blocks it.

```
class Hangman():
    async def main(message):
        await Hangman.make_guess(message)

    async def update_score(message):
        sheetLoaded = Spreadsheet.load_ws(...)
            userExists = Spreadsheet.user_exists(...)
            if (not userExists):
                Spreadsheet.add_user(...)
            Spreadsheet.add_score(...)
            await Hangman.bot.send_message(message.channel, msg)

        elif (not sheetLoaded):
            await Hangman.bot.send_message(message.channel, msg)

    async def make_guess(message):

        # perform guess

        if (matched):      
            await Hangman.bot.send_message(message.channel, msg)
            Hangman.GAMES.pop(message.server.id)
            await Hangman.update_score(message)
```

When `Hangman.update_score()` is called it blocks it. so it won't process any commands until the score has been updated which means for about 5 or so seconds (not long but with lots of users spamming it it's an issue) the bot does not accept any other messages

What am i missing to be able to make the process run in the background while still accept new inputs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Asyncio is still single-threaded. The only way for the event loop to run is for no other coroutine to be actively executing. Using yield from/await suspends the coroutine temporarily, giving the event loop a chance to work. So unless you call another coroutine using `yield (from)` or `await` or `return`, the process is blocked. You can add `await asyncio.sleep(0)` in between steps of `Hangman.update_score` to divide the process blocking in multiple parts, but that will only ensure less "hanging" time, not actually speed up your thread.

To make the process actually run in the background, you could try something along the lines of:

```
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor
executor = ProcessPoolExecutor(2)
asyncio.ensure_future(loop.run_in_executor(executor, Hangman.update_score(message)))
```